# No route found while getting map direction through intent

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, driving-directions

I am trying to find map direction between two location.
source location is device location.
destination location is database which I maintain.
Here is my code.
I am able to reach the screen where I choose transit mode bus ,train,subway 
but I get result like No route found.
I am able to see "My Location " in From field 
and latitude and longitude in to location
Here is my code for get direction.

```
protected void getDirections() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double dlongtd =result.get(0).getLongitude() ,dlattd=result.get(0).getLatitude();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr="+dlongtd+","+dlattd));
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
            "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

this the dialog box I get
and when I click any one of the transit I get no routs found toast
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Mistake which I did above is
I was passing longitude instead of latitude and vice versa.Everything works fine now

updated code:

```
protected void getDirections() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double dlongtd =result.get(0).getLongitude() ,dlattd=result.get(0).getLatitude();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr="+dlattd+","+dlongtd));
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
            "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way we can mask the latitude and longitude of from box with word of our choice...?

Comment: I made the same mistake